# Degree of extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> How to find the degree of $\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]2\right) $ over $\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt2\right)$ ?

I know how to find  $\mathbb Q\left(\sqrt2\right)$ over $\mathbb Q$.
But i am confused in above question.Please someone guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = \sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{2} \Rightarrow (x-\sqrt{2})^3 = 2$. Expand this you get a cubic polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Does this suffice to conclude that the degree of extension is $3$?...

Comment: answer is correct.Same way i thought The answer but I was not sure.